# Global variable overrides session variable in PHP

Tags: php, session

I found weird behavior in PHP, it looks like "reversed register globals". First try this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = NULL;
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

This outputs nothing. Then change line 2:

```
session_start();
$test = 1;
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

This outputs "1"!

This only happens if I set $_SESSION['test'] to NULL!

Register globals if 100% off.

My hosting provider has PHP 5.2.17. This does not happen on my local 5.3.6.

Is this a bug or is there a setting for this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 5.3.2; but there's a warning, " Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect which existed until PHP 4.2.3."... and a reference to the `session.bug_compat_42` configuration flag. Can you post complete code?

Comment: Can not reproduce on 5.2.5. http://codepad.org/b02TTy5E

Comment: @Robert: Please add your solution as an answer below (yes you can answer your own questions). That done you're able to mark it as "the answer" later on which will mark this question as solved then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @hakre: I had to wait 8 hours before answering my question and now I have to wait 2 days to mark it as answer... What's up with that?

Comment: @Robert: That's normal, just some timings to prevent too quick self-answers in general I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

I changed php.ini from:

```
session.bug_compat_42 = On
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
```

To:

```
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
```

Thanks Kerrek SB!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't happen for me

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/b61fd.php

Try to contact your support, but I think it's not possible

Comment: You'd better put `var_dump` there. With just `echo`ed code doesn't seem to be even run.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using PHP v5.2.17?

Check

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

This shouldn't be happening in 4.3.0 and later...